# How to fix: Changed My Angular Project To SCSS - Now No Components Render

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I am trying to integrate MdBootstrap with my current Angular application, which is using regular CSS. I followed their quick-start/installation guide here: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/

Now, my components won't render. The compilation succeeds, but all I get is a blank screen (with purple background thanks to my src/styles.scss).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzhPV.png

Here is my angular.json:

```
"schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/esports-platform-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
          },
```

And here is my app.component.html:

```html
<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And here is my HomeComponent's html:

```html
<app-main id="mainDisplay" class="hidden" [userLoggedIn]="userLoggedIn"></app-main>


<app-login id="loginDisplay" [userLoggedIn]="userLoggedIn"></app-login>
```

*EDIT*: Here is my side-nav.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-side-nav',
    templateUrl: './side-nav.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './side-nav.component.scss' ]
})
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And here is my side-nav.component.html:

```html
<!-- SideNav slide-out button -->
<a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mdbBtn color="primary" class="p-3 button-collapse"><mdb-icon fas icon="bars"></mdb-icon></a>
<!--/. SideNav slide-out button -->

<!-- Sidebar navigation -->
<mdb-side-nav #sidenav class="fixed" [fixed]="true">
  <!-- Logo -->
  <li>
    <div class="logo-wrapper waves-light">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb-transparent.png" class="img-fluid flex-center"></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!--/. Logo -->
  <!--Social-->
  <li>
    <ul class="social">
      <li><a class="icons-sm fb-ic"><mdb-icon fab icon="facebook-f"> </mdb-icon></a></li>
      <li><a class="icons-sm pin-ic"><mdb-icon fab icon="pinterest"> </mdb-icon></a></li>
      <li><a class="icons-sm gplus-ic"><mdb-icon fab icon="google-plus"> </mdb-icon></a></li>
      <li><a class="icons-sm tw-ic"><mdb-icon fab icon="twitter"> </mdb-icon></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!--/Social-->
  <!--Search Form-->
  <li>
    <form class="search-form" role="search">
      <div class="form-group md-form waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
  </li>
  <!--/.Search Form-->
  <!-- Side navigation links -->
  <li>
    <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
      <mdb-accordion [multiple]="false" aria-multiselectable="false">

        <!-- Collapsible link -->
        <mdb-accordion-item>
          <mdb-accordion-item-head mdbWavesEffect><mdb-icon fas icon="chevron-right"></mdb-icon> Collapsible menu
          </mdb-accordion-item-head>
          <mdb-accordion-item-body>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" mdbWavesEffect>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" mdbWavesEffect>Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </mdb-accordion-item-body>
        </mdb-accordion-item>

        <!-- Simple link -->
        <mdb-accordion-item class="no-collase">
          <mdb-accordion-item-head mdbWavesEffect><mdb-icon far icon="hand-pointer"></mdb-icon> Simple link
          </mdb-accordion-item-head>
          <mdb-accordion-item-body></mdb-accordion-item-body>
        </mdb-accordion-item>

        <!-- Collapsible link -->
        <mdb-accordion-item>
          <mdb-accordion-item-head mdbWavesEffect><mdb-icon far icon="eye"></mdb-icon> Collapsible menu 2
          </mdb-accordion-item-head>
          <mdb-accordion-item-body>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" mdbWavesEffect>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" mdbWavesEffect>Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </mdb-accordion-item-body>
        </mdb-accordion-item>

        <!-- Simple link -->
        <mdb-accordion-item class="no-collase">
          <mdb-accordion-item-head mdbWavesEffect><mdb-icon far icon="gem"></mdb-icon> Simple link 2</mdb-accordion-item-head>
          <mdb-accordion-item-body></mdb-accordion-item-body>
        </mdb-accordion-item>

      </mdb-accordion>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!--/. Side navigation links -->
  <div class="sidenav-bg mask-strong"></div>
</mdb-side-nav>
<!--/. Sidebar navigation -->
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Why isn't my login component showing up after the switch to SCSS from CSS?

Comment: is there any errors in console

Comment: Wow, yea there are when I inspect with Google Chrome. https://i.imgur.com/9IN17Zj.png looks like a lot of it comes from the mdb tags I add in my side-nav component

Comment: I removed all the html from my sidenav my component came alive again! But I'd like to be able to use the mdb tags... i have imported the MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot() ... not sure why it won't compile the <mdb-stuff>

Comment: it's really hard to guess the issue mate, please share errors or codes that you use to configure the component.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph I edited the question to have the component.ts and .html

Comment: so, is the issue still as in the screenshot?

Comment: just remove `[fixed]="true"` as its not a prop for your side-nav component

Comment: S.OF is trying to tell me to not have extended discussions in comments. I'm not able to use any custom tags even when I remove the properties. Nice catch but it still aint workin :/

Comment: looks like bootstrap is not added to your project properly I think css is not causing any issue here